# How to unpack without a loop with python?

Tags: python, unpack

I am coding like this:

```
num = [i for i in range(int(len(y)/8))]
    for i in num:
        value.append(struct.unpack_from('d',bytearray(y),offset=i*8))
```

Where `y` is a arround 65000 bytes array, and value is a list of arround 8000 integers. And it is taking too long to execute.

Is there any way to divide a bitearray in packages of 8 bytes and umpack them without a loop?

Comment: `value = struct.unpack('8000d', y)`?

Comment: Dear Amadan, please include you coment as answer and I will acept it. Cheers!